# My data lies on a linear plane

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-visualization

My purpose is to classify 3 classes from an EEG data. When I plotted my data on feature space in order to visualize, I found they lie on such a linear plane (please see my figures). Before plotting, I had applied several methods for feature extraction (ex: Common Spatial Pattern, ...)

I will explain my procedures here briefly. I used Common Spatial Pattern. My data are EEG signals consisting of 2 channels. I apply pass-band filter to extract 8 more sub-bands for each original channel. The sample rate is 128Hz, and I chose Windows size is 1 second, so my data at 1 second can be denoted as $\{E_n\}_{i=1}^M \in R^{\rm{channel} \times 128}$ where $M$ is a number of trial. Each trial will be associated with a specific class. I'm trying to find $W$ such that $W^\intercal E = S$ and $S_n \in R^{d \times 128}$ ($d<\rm{channel}$). Each trial's feature is $(x_1 ... x_d)$ where $x_i = \log \bigl(\frac{var(s_i)}{\sum{s_i}}\bigr)$. I chose $d=2$ for figure 1 and $d=3$ for figure 2 and plotted $S$.

My question is: what is the phenomenon? Is the problem in my data or feature extraction?

[image: I projected onto 2D plane]
[image: I projected onto 3D plane, each color correspond with one class]

Comment: You will need to explain what procedures you applied for feature extraction. Otherwise there is little additional one can say: your data have a linear dependence.  When you edit your question, please explain what your figures mean, because there is no obvious connection between them.

Comment: sorry, I wrote caption for my figures but I don't know why they disappear.

Comment: I fixed your captions, so if you could explain what your feature extraction procedures were, everything should be ok for re-opening your question.

Comment: While you edited my question, I was editing so your corrections are gone. But I made my procedure more clearly